# Dagger2: no injector factory bound for fragment

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I'm trying to convert a project that I'm building to use the dagger-android API for the DI framework, but I'm running into a dead end with an IllegalArgumentException when trying to inject a fragment using @ContributesAnroidInjector.

The relevant modules and components are included below:

**ApplicationComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
    ApplicationModule.class,
    ActivityBindingModule.class,
    DataManagerModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {

DataManagerContract getDataManager();

void inject(MyApplication application);

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {

    @BindsInstance
    ApplicationComponent.Builder application(Application application);

    ApplicationComponent build();
    }
}
```

my **ActivityBindingModule.java**:

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MainActivityModule.class)
    abstract MainActivity bindMainActivity();

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = SplashActivityModule.class)
    abstract SplashActivity bindSplashActivity();

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = LoginActivityModule.class)
    abstract LoginActivity bindLoginActivity();
}
```

**MainActivityModule.java**

```
@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @Binds
    abstract MainActivityContract.Presenter provideMainActivityPresenter(MainActivityPresenter presenter);

    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract HomeFragment provideHomeFragment();

    @FragmentScope
    @Binds
    abstract HomeFragmentContract.Presenter provideHomeFragmentPresenter(HomeFragmentPresenter presenter);

    // Inject other fragments and presenters
}
```

SplashActivity and LoginActivity only depend on their respective presenters, and dagger works fine in these. But my MainActivity can contain numerous fragments and causes a crash when trying to inject one of those fragments using:

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    ....
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
    ....
}
```

Here is my logcat for this crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<com.myapp.ui.main.Home.HomeFragment>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<com.myapp.ui.main.Home.HomeFragment>
        at dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.inject(DispatchingAndroidInjector.java:104)
        at dagger.android.support.AndroidSupportInjection.inject(AndroidSupportInjection.java:74)
        at com.myapp.ui.main.Home.HomeFragment.onAttach(HomeFragment.java:65)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1363)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1109)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:996)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:99)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2364)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3221)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3171)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:560)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6696)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I'm not sure where the problem in the code is. If I move the bindings for HomeFragment to the ActivityBindingModule, the app runs fine, but the crash comes back if I bring those bindings back into the MainActivityModule. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

```
public class MyApp extends DaggerApplication {

    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        return DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().application(this).build();
    }
}
```

and my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements MainActivityContract.View,
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Inject
MainActivityContract.Presenter mPresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Open home fragment on first start
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Create new instance of HomeFragment
        HomeFragment homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, homeFragment)
                .commit();
    }

// Other logic
}
```

Comment: Does your Activity implement `HasFragmentInjector`? Could you include the code?

Comment: I edited my question to include the custom application which extends `DaggerApplication` and the main activity which will contain my fragments. The activity does not implement `HasFragmentInjector`. My impression was that by extending `DaggerApplication` I didn't have to implement `HasFragmentInjector` in my activity

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you inject using `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)` from your `HomeFragment`, Dagger will walk the parent-fragment hierarchy to find someone that implements `HasSupportFragmentInjector`. To make it work, make your `MainActivity` extends `DaggerAppCompatActivity` which implements `HasSupportFragmentInjector`.

From the doc of `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(Fragment fragment)`:

> Injects {@code fragment} if an associated {@link
>   dagger.android.AndroidInjector} implementation can be found, otherwise
>   throws an {@link IllegalArgumentException}.
>
> Uses the following algorithm to find the appropriate {@code
>   AndroidInjector} to use to inject {@code fragment}:
>
> 1. Walks the parent-fragment hierarchy to find the a fragment that implements {@link
>          HasSupportFragmentInjector}, and if none do
>
>    Uses the {@code fragment}'s {@link Fragment#getActivity() activity} if it implements
>          {@link HasSupportFragmentInjector}, and if not
>
>    Uses the {@link android.app.Application} if it implements {@link
>          HasSupportFragmentInjector}.
>
> If none of them implement {@link HasSupportFragmentInjector}, a {@link
>   IllegalArgumentException} is thrown.
>
> @throws IllegalArgumentException if no parent fragment, activity, or
>   application implements
>       {@link HasSupportFragmentInjector}.

With this, Dagger will use

```
@FragmentScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract HomeFragment provideHomeFragment();
```

from your `MainActivityModule` to inject inside your `HomeFragment`.

Comment: Thanks, that make a lot of sense. Your work-around of using `@Inject HomeFragment homeFragment` seems like the obvious solution for an activity which only contains a single fragment, but in a situation where an activity can contain a larger number of fragments, it seems inefficient to inject an instance of every fragment in the `MainActivity`, no? Is there a way to do something similar but not inject an instance of every fragment, or only inject the fragment when it will be needed?

Comment: to inject the fragment only when it will be needed, you can use the lazy injection, see here: https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.10/dagger/Lazy.html

Comment: @C.Marr see my updated answer to make it work to way you really want it to

Comment: For those who are using `DaggerFragment` and faced this problem, what worked for me was that even though I wasn't injecting anything in the related Activity but I had to extend it from `DaggerAppCompactActivity` and also need to provide it with `@ContributesAndroidInjector()` like I was already doing for the Fragment.

Answer (score 4):

There could be other scenarious, where I got similar errors:

**Possible case 1:**
When you have a `DialogFragment` shown from a `Fragment`.
It's important to use the same FragmentManager.

For instance you have a "fragment-scoped screen":

```
@FragmentScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [HomeInjectors::class])
abstract fun provideHomeFragment() HomeFragment
```

With a subcomponent

```
@Module
abstract class HomeInjectors {

    @ChildFragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [DetailsModule::class])
    abstract fun provideDetailsFragment(): DetailsDialogFragment

}
```

Important here to note, that when you show a **dialog fragment**,
you should use **child fragment manager** not the Activity's one.

in this case, if you show dialog from the HomeFragment,

```
detailsDialog.show(activity.supportFragmentManager, "some tag)
```

and

```
detailsDialog.show(requireFragmentManager(), "some tag)
```

will not work.

You should do instead:

```
detailsDialog.show(childFragmentManager, "some tag)
```

**Possible case 2:**   Parent fragment with child fragments.

In order to make child fragments with "smaller" scope (Sample code is the same as above, but consider DetailsDialogFragment a regular fragment and a child of the HomeFragment).

In my case, the child fragment wasn't able to find Parent's fragment injector.

The reason was that while providing a child fragment injector, I mistakenly made my `BaseFragment implement HasFragmentInjector`.
However, since I use support fragments (AndroidX or whatever), I should have made `BaseFragment implement HasSupportFragmentInjector`

So the BaseFragment may look like:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

abstract class BaseFragment : SometFragment(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject lateinit var childFragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return childFragmentInjector
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
    }
}
```

It is useful when by certain reasons your "BaseFragment" must have other than `DaggerFragment` parent

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I did not define the `Fragment` in @`Module` class! so When I added it like :

```
@ActivityScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {ActivityModule.class})
abstract InvestmentDetailsFragment bindInvestmentDetailsFragment();
```

my problem fixed!